# Marklogic Plural/Singular Stemming

Tags: marklogic

Is there any way to limit Marklogic stemming search to singular/plural variations only and disable all other stemming variations?. I am aware of custom dictionaries in Marklogic, but that means I have to statically redesign the whole dictionary and that will affect other cases where the full stemming search is needed.

So, what I am looking for is a simpler way/option in Marklogic stemming search that enables only plural/singular stemming (mainly for English language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than one setting related to the level of stemming, there is really no tool for tuning the stemming:

MarkLogic 7/8
You may find custom dictionaries useful for this:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/custom-dictionaries

MarkLogic 9
Jammed pack with new tokenizing and stemming features - including custom tokenizing and stemming. This may fit you even better once its released.